# how to localize the active record error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I try to figure out how I can localize the error item name in my rails application which appear when a user sign's up with uncorrect datas... I figured out how to override the messages but not the names of the messages like ("password", "login", "email", ...)

```
de:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            password_confirmation:
              blank: ""
            password:
              confirmation: ""
              blank:  ""
              too_short: ""
            login:
              taken: ""
              blank: ""
              too_short: ""
            email:
              taken: ""
              blank: ""
              too_short: ""
              invalid: ""
      template:
        header: ""
        body: ""
```

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the i18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) this should work:

```
de:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        login: Anmeldung
```

Comment: What about :base type of errors? Should it be under the :attributes key?

Comment: It would be worth looking at the linked guide. There are a few options.

Comment: I've read it. My question was about custom validations. I'm sorry, the answer is really simple, I should provide custom key like this, for example: activerecord.errors.facts.base.same_login