# How to localize ActiveModel error messages in Rails 3?

Tags: validation, localization, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_presense_of :first_name
  validates_length_of :last_name, :in => 3..20, :too_long => "pick a shorter last name", :too_short => "pick a longer last name"

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name
end
```

How do you

1. localize error message(s) for :first_name
2. localize error message(s) for :last_name

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501019/how-to-localize-the-active-record-error-messages

Answer (score 1):

You're using a model without a database, right? You have to extend your class with the Translation Class of ActiveModel like this:

```
class User
  [...]
  extend ActiveModel::Translation
  [...]
```